# Conjugate of a partition

Tags: algorithm, partition

How to find a conjugate of a partition? I want to know if there's an algorithm. I know the Ferrers- Young diagram. Like `7 = 4+2+1` and the conjugate is `7=3+2+1+1`. Is it possible to find it without drawing the diagram?

Comment: I don't think this is an appropriate question for SO, which is a programming site; have you considered [math.se]?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.
Decrement all non-zero items of partition and count their number at every stage

```
 4 + 2 + 1   3 non zeros => 3
 becomes
 3 + 1 + 0   2 non zeros => 2
 2 + 0       1 non zero => 1
 1           1 non zero => 1
 result is 3 2 1 1
```

Of course, you don't need to decrement items explicitly - just count items >= MinValue at every step